# Why doesn't my GridView show up?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

EDIT: I forgot to bind the datatable (oops), that is now fixed.  The program now crashes, and I am still confused as too why.

I am making a website where I want to display a data table that has had its rows and columns switch.  I wrote some c# to do this.  My code compiles and runs without crashing, but the gridview where I put this data never shows up.  If I remove the code binding the data to the gridview, and instead use a sql source connection, it shows (but obviously is not flipped).

Why is my gridview not showing up and how would I go about fixing it?

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MachineUpdateFrontEnd
{
    public partial class NewUpdate : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataSet input;
        DataSet output;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet temp = pullData(UpdateSqlDataSource.ConnectionString);
            input = SwitchRows(temp);
            GridView1.DataSource = input.Tables[0];
        }

        private DataSet pullData(string ConStr) {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MachineUpdate", ConStr);
            adp.Fill(ds, "MachineUpdate");
            return ds;
        }

        private void pushData() {
            output = SwitchRows(input);
        }

        private DataSet SwitchRows(DataSet input)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            foreach (DataTable dt in input.Tables) {
                DataTable inputTable = new DataTable();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
                    inputTable.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
                }
                DataRow r;
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++) {
                    r = inputTable.NewRow();
                    r[0] = dt.Columns[j].ToString();
                    for (int k = 1; k < dt.Rows.Count; k++) {
                        r[k] = dt.Rows[k - 1][j];
                    }
                    inputTable.Rows.Add(r);
                }
                ds.Tables.Add(inputTable);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

ASP:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewUpdate.aspx.cs" Inherits="MachineUpdateFrontEnd.NewUpdate" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataKeyNames="UpdateID" style="margin-top: 0px" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty ="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateID" HeaderText="UpdateID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="UpdateID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineID" HeaderText="MachineID" SortExpression="MachineID" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID ="UpdateSqlDataSource" runat ="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MachineUpdateDataBaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MachineUpdate MQ]">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Entire project:

https://github.com/Darokrithia/MachineUpdateFrontEnd

Comment: Did you debug your code? Make sure the resulting DataSet contains data?

Comment: @mason  Aside from running it I am not sure how to go about doing this

Comment: I'm about to teach you one of the most valuable things in your career. You will be able to step through your code line by line, inspecting the values as you go. This will allow you to spot differences between how you think the code should be executing and how the code is actually executing. [Enjoy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @mason Yes, the row is filled.  It still crashes though

Comment: You're probably trying to access a column that doesn't exist in the DataRow, based on your comment on Rahul's answer. You're using `select *` in your SQL query. That's a code smell. You're saying "give me whatever columns are there" instead of saying which you want. That's likely to mask issues. Almost always when writing code, you should explicitly say which columns you want. Just when you're playing around with SQL should you use `select *`

Comment: @mason I am still new to sql (this whole project is for me to learn more).  I took that line from another answer on StackOverflow.  What command(s) should I use?  I do want all of the rows and columns to show up in the grid view.  Thank you again!

Comment: `select columnA, columnB, columnC, columnZ from mytable`. See how I explicitly specify which columns I want?

Comment: @mason  Okay, so I changed my command to "select UpdateID, MachineID from MachineUpdate"  These are the rows in the original data table, but it still crashes.  I think I might need to use the names of the new columns(as the rows have become columns and vice versa), but I have no idea what those would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see you are binding the gridview with the datasource like

```
GridView1.DataSource = input.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();   //missing data binding
```

Comment: Wow, that was dumb of me.  Now it's just crashing, which I guess is a step up.

The error is "System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'UpdateID'."  btw